# The nuget command failed: error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found

Tags: c#, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

Ok I am running my automated scripts in the pipeline and for some reason I can't get around the NugetCommand job as it throws the error:

```
error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found
```

I have defined the sdk within my yaml file as part of build as follows:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.x'
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: GitVersion@5
  inputs:
    runtime: 'core'
    configFilePath: 'GitVersion.yml'
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run tests
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(TestProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Exploring the many options I have found in here but none has worked, even changed the buildPlatform: 'anyCPU' to '64x' thinking this would suffice but still no luck.  Any help would be aprreciated?

csproj is below:

```
Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="App1.config" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Chromium.ChromeDriver" Version="2.37.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.90" />
    <PackageReference Include="DapperExtensions" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExtentReports" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" Version="85.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.8.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit" Version="3.8.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.8.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="WebDriverChromeDriver" Version="2.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="MyProject\MyProject\ElementData\AdminData\" />

  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager">
            
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: share your csproj

Comment: Updated in original question

Comment: Could you add your whole pipeline?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej is this ok for you?

Comment: To diagnose the error, first look in the project file’s top-level  [Project element (MSBuild)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/project-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019)  to see what SDK is being used. In your case it is
```csharp
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

```

Comment: but I see there is no ‘<’ mentioned before the sdk. Can you make sure that it isn't causing the error.